# How do I pipe terminal standard output (stdout) to the clipboard?

Tags: command-line, clipboard, pipe

Say I want to **list the contents of a folder and directly paste them into a chat window** for a friend to see.

I realize I could do `ls > filename.txt` to create a file (`filename.txt`) with those contents; I'd then have to open or print the file and **manually select and copy the text block** (*which can be annoying/tedious*.)  I clearly could also select and copy the output of `ls` directly from within the terminal window.

**It would be much faster/easier to simply pipe standard output to the clipboard**.

What terminal command allows me to do this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-i-send-stdin-to-the-clipboard

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This can be done with either
[`xsel`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xsel)
or
[`xclip`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xclip)
command line utilities.  Since neither program comes with Ubuntu by default you'll need to first install them via Ubuntu Software or the terminal.  Here's how to install them using the terminal (but remember you only need one of these two):

```
sudo apt install xsel
sudo apt install xclip
```

Note: *If you're using Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) see this [Snap Shot's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180870/25082) instead.*

Now some examples.  If you want to copy the output of `ls` to the clipboard here's what you'd do:

- With `xsel`:

  ```
  ls | xsel -ib
  ```
- With `xclip`:

  ```
  ls | xclip -sel clip
  ```

**This can of course be utilized for other terminal commands as well**.  Let's say you want to paste your network info into a help forum.

- With `xsel`:

  ```
  sudo lshw -C network | xsel -ib
  ```
- With `xclip`:

  ```
  sudo lshw -C network | xclip -sel clip
  ```

**Make this even easier with a new bash alias!**

Edit your `~/.bash_aliases` file (if it doesn't exist yet create it first with `touch ~/.bash_aliases`).

Then add ***one*** (depending on which program you decided to go with) of the following:

```
alias copy='xclip -sel clip'
```

or

```
alias copy='xsel -ib'
```

Then save and close.

Now (after restarting your terminal) you can send standard output to the clipboard just by piping it to `copy` (or whatever you decide to name your new alias).

For example:

```
ls | copy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but do you know anything just for Linux terminal?

Comment: You don't have to restart the terminal; you can just `source ~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: @Mohamad These are for running inside an X server (as it provides the clipboard functionality).  If you don't have that, you need to do it in your terminal emulator.  How to do that, depends on the actual software you are using, as there is no de-facto standard for that.

Comment: If you also want to capture stderr (the errors that might occur with your command, besides stdout), you have to use e.g. `ls nonexisting_file 2>&1 | xclip -sel clipboard`, meaning you redirect stderr to stdout.

Comment: `[michael@devops ITSM-705]$ cat TwitterRTsCollectedIds.txt | xclip -sel clip
Error: Can't open display: (null)`

Comment: Isn't there a solution which makes use of default and already installed packages?

Answer (score 21):

If you are attempting to copy to the clipboard using Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) `xsel` or `xclip` will not work unless you are using X Windows as clipboard is only for graphical.  However, to pipe terminal standard output to the clipboard in WSL Ubuntu you can use `clip.exe`.  You can then paste into the WSL Ubuntu terminal with standard paste commands and the copied text will be available in Windows as well.  For example,

```
pwd | clip.exe
```

will copy the current working directory to the (Windows) clipboard.

This search result appears at the top when looking for ways to copy/paste text in WSL so I think it is worthwhile to mention this so readers do not needlessly install xsel or xclip in Ubuntu and instead use `clip.exe`.

Comment: Thank you for this addition!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do: copy the output of terminal in WSL Ubuntu so I can paste it in Windows apps. I can confirm that this works with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and WSL 2 on Windows 10. Just be sure to include the file name extension: **clip.exe**

Comment: I never would have guessed that I can use `clip`, a Windows command equivalent to `xclip` and `xsel`, in a GNU/Linux context. So indeed, thanks for this addition!

Answer (score 3):

For more recent Ubuntu versions with Wayland [`wl-copy`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/wl-clipboard.1.html) will do. To install it, run:

```
sudo apt install wl-clipboard
```

Example of usage:

```
ls | wl-copy
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `zsh` with [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), you can use the [`clipcopy`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/clipboard.zsh) command to pipe the `stdout` output to the clipboard, as shown in the following examples:

```
pwd | clipcopy
ifconfig | clipcopy
echo $PATH | clipcopy
neofetch | clipcopy
```

You don't need to pass any other parameters, the output is copied directly to the clipboard.

**Note:** You can also use the `clippaste` command to view what's currently inside the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the path of a file in command line, without any new line after paste:

```
realpath filename | xclip -r -selection c
```

The `-r` switch is necessary to avoid the new line generated after pasting.