# How to copy terminal command in clipboard without using mouse?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, clipboard

[image]

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

I want to copy this command into the clipboard so that I can paste it in a file or an Ask Ubuntu question easily.

I know I can copy this by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but I want to get a mouse free answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pipe terminal standard output (stdout) to the clipboard?](https://askubuntu.com/q/184397/295286)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That question was asked about terminal output, but my question is about terminal input(the command).

Comment: There's no mouse-less solutions for terminals. There are keyboard shortcuts to copy/paste *within* terminal itself, but nothing that copies into GUI clipboard, because none of those features interface with GUI clipboard anyway. The "Copy" feature from right click menu is feature of GUI windows, which  use same mechanism as what Ctrl+Shift+C. So easiest way is to echo the command via pipe to either of `xclip` or `xsel` as explained in the linked post.

Comment: As for input, `xclip -sel clip` alone reads from `stdin`, so you can just type in your command, then Ctrl+D, and it'll go to clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`bash`’s History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html), to copy the previous command line to your clipboard without performing command substitution, expansions etc. do:

```bsh
echo !!:q | xclip -sel clip # or respectively
echo !!:q | xsel -ib
```

`!!` is a shortcut for `!-1`, referring to the previous command. Colon `:` precedes the modifier `q`, which lets the expansion quote the substituted words with single quotes to prevent further substitutions.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ uname -r                        # run your command
4.10.0-35-generic
$ echo !!:q | xclip -sel clip     # copy the previous command to clipboard 
echo 'uname -r' | xclip -sel clip # this line shows what’s done
$ xclip -sel clip -o              # print clipboard content (just for testing)
uname -r
$ $(xclip -sel clip -o)           # run command stored in clipboard (just for testing)
4.10.0-35-generic
```

To simplify this you can [create an `alias`](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/507051) or set a keyboard shortcut in the settings. Read [`man bash`/HISTORY EXPANSION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc29) and [`man history`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/history.3readline.html) to learn more about history expansion.

Comment: @alhelal Added. :)

Comment: This works for some easy cases, but as soon as input/output redirection, command substitution or similar things (i.e. anything the shell interprets) come into play it won't copy the literal command to clipboard.

Comment: @LienhartWoitok You’re totally right, luckily there’s the modifier `q` to *[q]uote the substituted words, escaping further substitutions* – I edited my answer. Thanks a lot for this helpful remark!