# How do I delete the last "enter" of the copied content?

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard

According to [How do I pipe terminal standard output (stdout) to the clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184397/how-do-i-pipe-terminal-standard-output-stdout-to-the-clipboard), we could copy the current path via:

`pwd | xclip -sel clip`

However, in most cases, I want to further modify the copied path when I use it. For example, add some folders to the path before running the command:

```
cp (paste the path) (then, I want to add the target path)
```

But the pasted path have an "enter" at its end, so I don't have a chance to type my target path...

So, how could I copy the terminal standard output AND remove the last "enter" character?

Ps. I don't care how long the command is, as long as it works robustly.

Comment: Are you doing this in different terminals? If not, you can expand the value of `$PWD` in a command line and then edit the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` to trim trailing newline:

```
printf %s "$PWD" | xclip -sel clip
```

Comment: accept printf as the answer according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo (No one talked about speed though)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
echo -n $(pwd) | xclip -sel clip
```